# React hot reload not working with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

React hot reload is not working. 
In webpack entry, I have following code.

```
entry: {
        home: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8000', 
            'webpack/hot/dev-server', // add "only-dev-server" prevents reload on syntax errors
            path.join(__dirname, 'app/home-styles.js')
        ],
        main: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            path.join(__dirname, 'app/styles.js'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'app/vendor.js'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.js')
        ]
    },
```

and in dev-server I have hot = true;

and i have below code for wrapping Provider in hot

```
class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        const { store, history } = this.props;
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router history={history} routes={routes(store)}/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default hot(module)(Root);
```

This is result in console, but nothing happens when there is some change. So basically it appears as if hot reload is working but.. no changes reflects. What am I missing here. ?  [image]

I am using react 16.2.* and react-hot-loader @4.0.* an webpack @4.5.*

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue? i'm having a very similar one

Comment: no.. i decided to ignore it for now.. will look into it later.. if you ever find one ..please comment :P  you can set bounty to question.. someone will answer then :P

Comment: Are you using webpack Dev server?

Comment: yes we are using webpack Dev Server. why?

Comment: Do you access your application from the IP or map it to a domain?

Comment: @ClarkT. To a domain

Comment: we fixed ours by doing this..

Comment: @ClarkT. How ..can you explain a little bit

Comment: just posted an answer, couldnt post the code via comment sorry

Comment: have you tried using --hot in package.json or setting hot:true under devServerOptions like the answer below? for me i get reloading working but it never accepts the HMR updates being pushed so always does a full page reload on me but I guess it's 1 step better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

try updating your dev server config like so

```
const devServerOptions = {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    host: 'beta.whenidev.net',
    https: true,
  };
// if you're adding a dev server entry do it like this
  WebpackDevServer.addDevServerEntrypoints(config, devServerOptions);
```

Comment: hope it works for you, took us days to track it down. came down to use having the host set to an ip and not the domain.